# How to avoid two windows from this tkinter code?

Tags: matplotlib, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

The python code below was provided by NMech [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30774281/update-matplotlib-plot-in-tkinter-gui).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.createWidgets()
   
    def createWidgets(self):
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
        ax = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8], polar=True)
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
        canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.plotbutton = tk.Button(master=root, text="plot", command=lambda: self.plot(canvas, ax))
       self.plotbutton.grid(row=0, column=0)

    def plot(self, canvas, ax):
        c= ['r','b','g']
        ax.clear()
        for i in range(3):
            theta = np.random.uniform(0,360,10)
            r = np.random.uniform(0,1,10)
            ax.plot(theta,r,linestyle="None",marker='o',color=c[i])
            canvas.draw()

root=tk.Tk()
app=Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

The code displays two similar windows shown below. One window is the app labeled 'tk', and the second window is labeled 'Figure 1'. How do I modify the code so it only displays the app 'tk'?

[image: two-windows]

Comment: Hi there @TedErsek, I just tried your code, mine is just showing a single window with label tk?

Comment: I also don't get the "Figure 1" but I found the python process does not end when I close the tk window.  I tried replacing `fig = plt.figure` with `fig = matplotlib.figure.Figure`, then it worked as expected.  As I understand it, `pyplot` always does window management for you but in this case you are organising that for yourself so you don't want to use `pyplot` at all.